# Start a script from a keyframed animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm using the old animation system in Unity to keyframe in a camera path (no choice in this). What I'd like to know is if it's possible to have this animation start a script that starts an object to grow in scale depending on the distance of the camera.

I know there is a few ways I could go about this, but I'm specifically asking if it can be done via the animation component. If it is possible, please let me know.

Comment: And if you want something more stackoverflowy http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, something like that is easily possible with an [Animation Event](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html).

In your animation window, click on the appropriate section in your timeline to add an animation event.

[image]

To your object, add a script component that contains the appropriate function you want to call from that animation event. Let's say we create a simple "Test" script that has a `public void DoSomething()`.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start() {}

    void Update() {}

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Do Something");
    }
}
```

Then click on the animation event and a windows like the following should appear:

[image]

From the dropdown you should be able to select your method. Now, if you play your animation, then at the moment of your animation event, the appropriate method will be called.

That should do the trick.